# Apache2 on Debian freezes after some time

Tags: apache-2.2, php5

I have problem with apache server on Debian VPS. After some time (few hours) of work it freezes and no request is being processed (server allows connection but returns nothing).

```
# apache2 -v  
 Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)
 Server built:   Dec 23 2014 22:48:29


# apache2 -l
Compiled in modules:
  core.c
  mod_log_config.c
  mod_logio.c
  mod_version.c
  prefork.c
  http_core.c
  mod_so.c

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          1
    MinSpareServers       1
    MaxSpareServers      19
    MaxClients          19
    MaxRequestsPerChild   20
</IfModule>
```

This configuration is after some tests, low MaxRequestsPerChild seemed to help, but no, server still frezees.

When server is frozen its stuck in `poll` syscall:

```
# strace -p 30145
Process 30145 attached - interrupt to quit
restart_syscall(<... resuming interrupted call ...>) = 0
poll([{fd=25, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
poll([{fd=25, events=POLLIN|POLLERR|POLLHUP}], 1, 10000
[......]
```

and this continues. This backtrace result from gdb:

```
#0  0x00007eff42499d13 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007eff3f35bf50 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#2  0x00007eff3f16a5b2 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#3  0x00007eff3f34fa65 in _php_stream_fill_read_buffer () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#4  0x00007eff3f34fba7 in _php_stream_read () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#5  0x00007eff3f2cc14a in zif_fread () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#6  0x00007eff3f4411c1 in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#7  0x00007eff3f3fab77 in execute () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#8  0x00007eff3f399a1c in zend_execute_scripts () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#9  0x00007eff3f339393 in php_execute_script () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#10 0x00007eff3f4438ba in ?? () from /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
#11 0x00007eff4326bdc0 in ap_run_handler ()
#12 0x00007eff4326c20b in ap_invoke_handler ()
#13 0x00007eff4327c448 in ap_process_request ()
#14 0x00007eff432792c8 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007eff43272780 in ap_run_process_connection ()
#16 0x00007eff432811ee in ?? ()
#17 0x00007eff43281942 in ?? ()
#18 0x00007eff432824a6 in ap_mpm_run ()
#19 0x00007eff432568e6 in main ()
```

So it looks it's stuck in PHP:

```
# php -v
PHP 5.4.36-0+deb7u3 (cli) (built: Jan  9 2015 08:07:06) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

Any hints what is going? Configuration and code is basically unchanged, only updates to packages and Wordpress were applied (this site runs few small Wordpress instances and static sites. Memory usage is approx 800 MB when VPS is with 1G of RAM. CPU is idle...